# excluding my executable from the Program Compatibility Assistant

Tags: windows, manifest

I'm trying to have a executable excluded by the PCA. After reading [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/2545347/excluding-programs-from-the-program-compatibility-assistant-pca), I used resource hacker to add a manifest with administrator permission. But after doing that, although the application now prompts for administration privilege it still isn't excluded by the PCA.

I want this executable excluded by PCA in all windows version after Windows XP. The reason being it no longer works properly after running it once. On first run it works correctly, but after the first run and PCA added it to its list of programs it no longer works.

This is the manifest I inserted and I'm using windows 10.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
      <application> 
        <!--This Id value indicates the application supports Windows Vista functionality -->
          <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
        <!--This Id value indicates the application supports Windows 7 functionality-->
          <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
        <!--This Id value indicates the application supports Windows 8 functionality-->
          <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
        <!--This Id value indicates the application supports Windows 8.1 functionality-->
          <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
      </application> 
  </compatibility>
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" 
                    name="myOrganization.myDivision.mySampleApp" 
                    version="6.0.0.0" 
                    processorArchitecture="x86" 
                    publicKeyToken="0000000000000000"
  />
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
        <dpiAware  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>  
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
  <security>
     <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
     </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
 </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Hmm, that support article is very dated, talking about the usage of PCA during the XP to Vista transition.  PCA got a lot more use after that.  You can't get good advice if you don't tell us anything about the specific shim being applied, but surely you'll need to leverage the ExecutablesToExclude registry entry.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure but deleting the value in the registry key `Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\AppCompatFlags\\Compatibility Assistant\\Store` makes the app work properly again. But I have to delete it each time I execute the app.